# PSImaging error: Exception has been thrown by the target

Tags: ocr, powershell-4.0

I have the Positronic-IO setup on one of my servers, and am attempting to set it up on a second where I will actually be performing the OCR. I can get it to install, but when attempting to call the Export-ImageText I receive the subject mentioned error.

I recall having a difficult time to get it to work on the first server as well. I guess I should have taken better notes.  Does this require a re-start of the server??

Comment: Maybe you should follow this issue: https://github.com/Positronic-IO/PSImaging/issues/5

Comment: Thanks, Wovano, I am.  I am the user that listed +1.